# How can i reverse numbers with loop

Tags: javascript

I trued to use my code that was written in c++ to output reversed number with while loop and i got output of "Infinity"

Can somebody explain why it happened and is there any other method to make it with loop instead of split().reverse().join()

Here is my code:

```
var n = 352, reverse = 0, remainder;

while (n>0) {
    remainder = n%10;
    reverse = reverse * 10 + remainder;
    n = n / 10;
}

console.log(reverse);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only missing term is rounding of the number to nearest integer.
Here is updated code.

```
var n = 352, reverse = 0, remainder;

while (n>0) {
    remainder = n%10;
    reverse = reverse * 10 + remainder;
    n = Math.floor(n / 10);
}

console.log(reverse);
```

Comment: Try console.log(352/10); and console.log(Math.floor(352/10); You will understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
 n = parseInt(n / 10);
```

instead of

```
 n = n / 10;
```